# How to add FsLexYacc to a project via PackageReference

Tags: f#

I do not see how to install fslex on my mac os.  According to https://fsprojects.github.io/FsLexYacc/fslex.html, I will need to add a package reference somewhere in a file:

[image: screenshot]

But which file should the package reference added to? I suppose there is a kind of project description xml file that all F# developers use. Where can I find documentation about such a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add

```
<PackageReference Include="FsLexYacc" Version="9.0.2" />
```

to your project's `.fsproj` file.  The FsLexYacc README assumes, incorrectly, that when it tells you to add a package reference "to your project" that you know that you should put it in your `.fsproj` file.  Every F# project will should have exactly one `.fsproj` file in it.

`.fsproj` files are essentially the same as their C# equivalent `.csproj` files, for which you can [find documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj).

Note that most .NET developers avoid tinkering directly with project files when they can avoid it.  For example, I would personally opt to [install this package from NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FsLexYacc/).